# Why do I see this message when I try to edit a tag wiki?

Tags: support, tag-wiki

I occasionally go and add descriptions to tag wikis and earn a little rep along the way. But *oftentimes* I see this message instead of an edit field where I can just update the tag description:

> [image]

What does this mean?

Comment: Can you share what page you saw the 'much higher' limit on? Also keep in mind that tag wiki edits and normal post edits are put in the same pile as far as your daily limit, although you are over 2k rep, so you shouldn't be seeing that hit you at all.

Comment: @remudada Do you see a blue "propose tag info" button below that orange/peach text box on that page?

Comment: When you only write a tag wiki about a topic you say you believe to know something about, then why there all 5 pending tag wiki edits from you copied from somewhere else? (i.e. plagiarism) (for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24875140, https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24889604, https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24889603, https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24889645, https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24889644)

Comment: @Tom good catch.  Every one of those appears to be plagiarized from the start of the relevant Wikipedia article.  Plagiarized content is *NOT* acceptable.

Comment: If your previous tag wiki edits were also copypasta, when you're able to submit edits again please go back and start submitting edits that replace the plagiarized text you submitted with something written in your own words.  A history of plagiarized content will leave you open for moderator sanctions if one ever happens to notice what you've done.  The past can't be undone; but you can correct your mistakes and demonstrate that you understand what is acceptable behavior now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are seeing is the placeholder text that is shown on the Tag Info page, when the Tag Wiki and/or Tag excerpt are empty.

Generally you can use the blue "[Propose Tag Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSFfZl.png)" button below the those boxes to add those missing descriptions.

In your case you are missing this button, because [you already have more than 5 suggestions pending](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2159583/remudada?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), which exceeds [the rate limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281202).